# Drupal user authentication check

Tags: javascript, php, module, drupal-modules, event-hooking

I have been trying to write a function to check if user is authenticated and then call a google analytics script for custom report. This has been a big hassle and I believe Drupal is not that difficult. Is there anyone who can help or take up the project?
It should be a simple and straight forward thing to do but being able to check user authentication has not been easy

I've tried to use a php function to check if user is logged in but I was not able to call javascript function from it.

I wrote a script function with jquery calling the script on page load but I was not able to check if user is logged in using javascript

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best option, but...

1. What do you think about calling, from your JS function, a custom module's controller, that return `true` if...
   `$currentUser = \Drupal::currentUser(); $uid = $currentUser->id();` returns a numeric value higher than `0` or `false` if the value returned is `0` (anonymous user)? This controller only should had to return the UID of the current user in a JSON format, readable afterwards from your JS.
2. Another try would be to write a YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_page() function in your theme's .theme file that implement the above check, and send the value to the template, in order to render the value in a 'data-attribute' in some DOM element. Once rendered, you could access the value from your JS.

None of these approachs are 'Drupal way' of doing the stuff, but... hope these help you.

Cheers.